# Is adding a condition on distance before sqrt a performance gain for this code?

Tags: c#, performance, optimization, distance, sqrt

Let me pose a hypothetical question. Given these two blocks of C# code, is the second version faster? I've researched and tested/timed this quite a bit and I have my own theory (which I will keep to myself for now to not influence the answers), but I want to ask the question here to keep my own biases in check. The reason why I'm studying this is because it was asked in an interview question recently, and I'm not satisfied with how the result was discussed. Thank you in advance.

First version:

```
public float DistanceBetweenPoints(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2)
{
    float result;
    float xDifference = Math.Abs(x1 - x2);
    float yDifference = Math.Abs(y1 - y2);
    result = (float) Math.Sqrt(xDifference * xDifference + yDifference * yDifference);
    return result;
}
```

Second version:

```
public float DistanceBetweenPoints(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2)
{
    float result;
    float xDifference = Math.Abs(x1 - x2);
    float yDifference = Math.Abs(y1 - y2);

    if(xDifference > 0 || yDifference > 0)
    {
        result = (float) Math.Sqrt(xDifference * xDifference + yDifference * yDifference);
    }
    else
    {
        result = 0;
    }

    return result;
}
```

I'm specifically wondering if adding in the 0 distance check is an optimization. At this point, I'm going to give more context around this question. The first version was what I had submitted for a solution, and the second version was what the interviewer had insisted that I do to make the code more performant. Their claim was that the second version is up to 20 times faster than the original, but I highly disagree. If this was possible, then you can bet that Microsoft would have included that optimization within the Sqrt call itself. Not only that, but from my understanding, the call is usually implemented via hardware, and when I measured the timing of it, I was seeing about 4-5 ticks per call. It shows the same results with the "optimization" of the 0 distance check. That's very impressive, and I don't know if there is anything I can do to make it faster.

Comment: Second version is slower. How often do you expect `xDifference` and `yDifference` to both be zero?

Comment: I want to clarify my question (I'll edit it in just a moment). I'm not looking for the fastest implementation of a sqrt call, I'm wondering if adding in the conditions for zero distance around the sqrt is a performance gain.

Comment: Depends on whether Math.Sqrt implements the check itself internally. ILSpy doesn't decompile the code, so we can't tell. Its "possible" that the implementation might vary from one framework edition to another.

Comment: I used the Stopwatch class with a rolling average of 100 frames, and I ran the program for about 30 seconds to get an error spread. Here is what I was seeing:
Original Solution
Distance > 0: 4.0 ticks per call (+- 0.3 ticks per call over the life of the program)
Distance = 0: 3.7 ticks per call (+- 0.5 ticks per call over the life of the program)

"Optimized" Solution
Distance > 0: 4.2 ticks per call (+- 0.4 ticks per call over the life of the program)
Distance = 0: 4.0 ticks per call (+- 0.2 ticks per call over the life of the program)

Comment: For optimisation, `Math.Abs` is unnecessary

Answer (score 3):

As usual, instead of trying to fix "broken" framework code, you should be trying to fix your own broken algorithms. Because if there was a way to make `Math.Sqrt` faster, it would already be done.

Specifically for distances, chances are you don't need to actually calculate the distance, the squared distance suffices (or again, fix your algorithm to make it suffice). That means you can drop the `Math.Sqrt` call completely!

Comment: The question specifically asked for the distance, so unfortunately, I can't just ignore it. But you definitely have a good point. Usually, the squared distance is enough, and I believe that a lot of game engines like Unity have dedicated methods for calculating that.